# Upload a photo in a LOCAL DRIVE (not URL) to a Facebook fan page using Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have searched extensively for the answer on Stackoverflow, and haven't been able to find it. I'm using the below code to upload a photo into my fan page in Facebook. It works.

**However,** as you can see the *picture* variable inside the *attach* dict refers to a URL. I'd like to be able to upload a **local** file (e.g., "/foo/bar/hello.png'). When I try to use a local path instead of a URL, it stops while executing .put_wall_post() with no printed error. It just stops, and response is not set to anything.

Would very much appreciate the input.

```
import facebook
import urllib 
import urlparse

access_token_page='XXX'
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = 'XXX'
FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID = 'XXX'

oauth_args = dict(client_id     = FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                  client_secret = FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
                  grant_type    = 'client_credentials')

oauth_response = urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' + urllib.urlencode(oauth_args)).read()                                  

attach = {
  "name": 'Hello world',
  "link": 'http://www.example.com',
  "caption": 'test post',
  "description": 'some test',
  "picture": 'http://somelocation.com/somepicture.png',
}


facebook_graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token_page)
try:
    response = facebook_graph.put_wall_post('', attachment=attach)
except facebook.GraphAPIError as e:
    print e
```

Comment: What's the error (sorry I don't have a facebook page setup to test out your code). Please edit your post and provide the whole trace.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast reply. I just updated the above. It stops while executing .put_wall_post() with no printed error.

Comment: From what I've gathered, the python libraries are not officially supported by facebook and certain things (uploading photos may be one of them) are only supported through official SDKs.  Look for a guy named Martey on Stackoverflow and try to message him.  He made a facebook library for python.

Comment: I maintain (but did not make) https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk. It is a fork of Facebook's original Python SDK, which is no longer officially supported. The SDK uses Facebook's Graph API, and so supports most, if not all, of the API's features - including uploading photos.

Comment: Thanks is exactly the library I was using (version 0.4.0). :-) Now it's working. See my question below to post as the page vs. my personal profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `put_photo` method to upload local data. To post it to a page, specify `<page id>/photos` as the `album_id`:

```
f.put_photo(open('picture.jpg'), message='Test photo upload', album_id='140231988803001/photos')
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Very much appreciated. An important clarification - how can I post it AS the page, and not as it is happening now, as an individual? Posts by the page appear large, while posts by my personal profile appear on the top right.

Comment: @mazemaker, try using your page access token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens